# Text falls to bottom of right column

Tags: html, css

I hope someone can help, I can't figure this out.  I am creating a wordpress theme using the _s template and I am having trouble with my right column.

If I put just a bunch of line breaks in, the flow is correct. However, as soon as I insert any text, img, or anything else, that data falls below the center column.

I know it is something simple that I am just not seeing.

Here is a link to the page.  http://juststin.com/test/help.html

And here is the css

```
.content-area {
        float: left;
}
.site-content {
        margin: 0 20%;
        width: 60%;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px;
        border-radius: 25px 25px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #333333;
        background: #ffffff;
}
.pictures {
        margin: 0 81%;
        width: 20%;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px;
        border-radius: 25px 25px;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ffffff;
        background: #ffffff;
}
.site-main .widget-area {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 0 -100%;
        width: 20%;
        background: #2E9AFE;
        background: #333333;
}
.site-footer {
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffffff;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px;
        border-radius: 25px 25px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #333333;
}
.site-header {
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffffff;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px;
        border-radius: 25px 25px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #333333;
}

.menu-div {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px;
        border-radius: 25px 25px;
        overflow: visible;
}

#page {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your weird column layout.  giving `margin-left -100%` to your `.widget-area` rather than just rendering it before your `#primary` column. Your `#pictures` column isn't floated so its flowing AFTER the `#primary` container who's `width` is 100%.

Option 1) put the column where it should go and don't use negative margins.

Option 2) assign a fixed width to `#primary` (looks like around 60%) and float `#pictures` left as well

Answer (score 0):

You really need some changes on your column layout markup. I edited your markup and css a little bit to make it work(I won't recommend you to use it.). Take a look at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hqi0MLTc

Off-topic:
Personally I prefer to use fixed width for sidebars/right left columns and fluid width for content area only.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Good suggestion on that fixed width.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that I had to decrease the size of the right side bar.  I am guessing that adding borders was increasing the sizes to over 100%.